# Scrape json data with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a son data in a div class where I am trying to get the data of "url" and I used `video_link = self.soup.find('div' ,{'class':'video-embed-big'})` but I am unable to get the data inside that div with a quoted url.

```
<div class="video-embed-big video-embed-area bf_dom" id="video_buzz_element_4154403_7994283" rel:thumb="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_Ym0LW_uPPk/2.jpg" rel:bf_bucket_data="{"video": {"size": "big", "width":"625", "height":"376", "url":"https://youtube.com/watch?v=_Ym0LW_uPPk", "id":"4154403_7994283"}}">
  <div style="position:relative;" id="video_wrapper_4154403_7994283">     
     <iframe id="yt_4154403_7994283" class="ytvideo" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="625" height="376" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_Ym0LW_uPPk?version=3&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://www.buzzfeed.com&amp;autoplay=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0">
          </iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
video_div = self.soup.find('div', id=lambda d: d and d.startswith('video_wrapper_'))
video_link = video_div.find('iframe')['src']
```

will return

```
In [5]: video_link
Out[5]: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/_Ym0LW_uPPk?version=3&hl=en&fs=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://www.buzzfeed.com&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque'
```

You can go a little more in depth if you want to use `urlparse` and get the actual youtube page.

```
import urlparse

video_div = self.soup.find('div', id=lambda d: d and d.startswith('video_wrapper_'))
video_link = video_div.find('iframe')['src']
url = urlparse.urlparse(video_link)
youtube_url = urlparse.urlunparse((url[0], url[1], "watch?v=" + url[2].split('/')[2],'','',''))
```

This is the output of `youtube_url`

```
In [15]: urlunparse((url[0], url[1], "watch?v=" + url[2].split('/')[2],'','',''))
Out[15]: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ym0LW_uPPk'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
video_link = self.soup.find('div',{'class':'video-embed-big'}).div.iframe['src']
```

You need to use the "." operator to go into the child of the div and then use the src attribute to get the url.